# dynmap rendered map not loading on web page

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to create a **locator map** that shows the location of all players on the server/in the world on Minecraft.

I am trying to use the **dynmap** plugin to do this.

I ran the command:

```
/dynmap radiusrender <world> 69 -6 200
```

And the Minecraft world told me: **'radiusrender completed'**.

However, when I tried to view the rendered map using my **server ID (ID)** and **the port** 8123:

```
http://ID:8123
```

The page was blank and the map did not appear.

I also specified the following in the **configuration.txt** file, but the page still remained blank:

```
deftemplatesuffix: vlowres
```

Comment: This is not technical support in the sense the closing reason is intended. It is not asking for help running a game or mod, but for help using a mod. It might be a better fit for GameDev, but isn't off-topic here.

Comment: I would think this question would be better on the Minecraft mods tags since this is not vanilla commands.